# HTML playing embedded youtube video in localhost server displays Video Unavailable

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have tried a few ways to play youtube videos on my HTML web page but each method I try I get the error "This video is unavailable" in the youtube frame.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
<object height="385" width="640">
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{{ videoID }}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
         allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" height="385" width="640">
</object>
```

Is there a way to work around this error, whether through python or javascript?
I have also tried the youtube API but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using the "F12" debugging in browsers? Difficult to tell what kind of issues you're running into here. Is it Youtube not wanting to play it to you or something else.

Comment: @Konrads I got this error:
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.  am I missing a property in my HTML tag?